# Java: Generics, superclass type reference pointing to <? extends superclass> type reference

Tags: java, generics

In the following code that I tried to compile:

```
List<Animal> animals;
List<? extends Animal> some;
animals = some;
```

I got the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#2-of ? extends Animal> to List<Animal>
```

But a list containing `<? extends Animal>` is guaranteed to contain at least `Animal` type in it, so why this error? Is this because if it's allowed, I can then put any random subclass object of `Animal` into 'animals' list, or is it something else?

Comment: `List<? extends Animal>` means it is a list of some unknown type that is either `Animal` or a subclass of `Animal`. `List<Animal>` can accept any `Animal`, but `List<Lion>` (which is safely converted treated as `List<? extends Animal>`) obviously cannot. Hopefully you understand :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001551/java-generics-superclass-type-reference-pointing-to-extends-superclass-typ#comment16007094_12001551).

`List<? extends Animal>` means it is a list of some unknown type that is either `Animal` or a subclass of `Animal`. `List<Animal>` can accept any `Animal`, but `List<Lion>` (which is safely treated as `List<? extends Animal>`) obviously cannot.

This is a classic example of [upper-bounded wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html). Make sure you read the Java Tutorial.

---

In the case you merely want a `List<Animal>` containing all of the elements of your `List<? extends Animal>`, you can merely do...

```
final List<? extends Animal> someAnimals = ...;
final List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>(someAnimals);
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `ArrayList` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) which takes `Collection<? extends E>`.

Answer (score 3):

`List<? extends Animal>` means that the list contains all instances of an unknown subtype of `Animal`, e.g. `List<Cat>`, `List<Dog>` and so on.

`List<Animal>` instead could might contain both `Cat`, `Dog` instances, therefore the cast is not legal.

Answer (score 1):

Because `List<? extends Animal>` is not a subtype of `List<Animal>`. If your assignment was legal than you could add a Dog object to a list of Cat. Like this:

```
List<Animal> cats = new List<Animal>();
cats.add(new Cat());
List<Dog> dogs = cats; //if was legal
dogs.add(new Dog)); //now you have a dog in a list of cats
```

Beware of arrays! With arrays the assignment is legal and the problem is not caught at compile time but at run time. For example:

```
Animal[] cats = new Animal[] {...};
Dogs[] dogs = cats; // OK at compile time
```